# Postfix Authentication not working from nodemailer

Tags: linux, ssl, postfix

I have the following as my nodemailer script:

```
'use strict';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'localhost.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
         user: 'user',
         pass: 'pass',
    }
});

module.exports = (msg) => {
let { from, to, subject, html } = msg;
// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
    from,
    to,
    subject, // plain text body
    html,
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
  });
}
```

When I try to run the function I receive the following error:

```
{ Error: 139970611431232:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:
code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }
```

I did have my config setup for postfix to use port 465 and 587 and still got the same response. Perhaps it's an issue with calling on localhost even though my postfix server is setup with the host being the domain to my website? I do have my postfix setup with ssl as well. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Update: I'm 90% sure this is an issue with the credentials I'm providing to nodemailer but I can't find out where the disconnect lies. The postfix server is working fine at sending messages on its own but not via a script. I've tried different ports and different config setups but I can't figure out what's going wrong and the error is not very helpful.

This is my postfix main.cf file

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = 
btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
# inbound
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
# outbound
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permite_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = zacharyhill.xyz
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inter_protocols = all
```

In the nodemailer script, I am passing in my username and password of the account on my server that is receiving the mail. I can send and receive mail just fine via the command line but I have not had any successfully sent through this script. Thanks a lot for any help. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried allowing the port numbers via ufw.

Here's my /etc/postfix/master.cf file as well:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

I get this error on any attempt..

```
{ Error: 139776600639296:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:
code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }
```

Update: Still having this issue... can't figure out what is wrong in my postfix setup that is allowing emails to be sent via the terminal but not via nodemailer.

Comment: Take a look at this:  https://serverfault.com/questions/669847/how-to-disable-sslv3-in-postfix-2-11

Comment: I tried this and restarted postfix. I received the same exact error

Comment: Same issue here - was your problem ever resolved?

Comment: Sadly it was not resolved

Answer (score 1):

Set the **secure flag to false**, the secure flag sets "SSL".  This does not mean your email will not be secure.  It will now use STARTTLS, which is even more secure!

```
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'localhost.com',
        port: 465,
     ->   secure: false,
        auth: {
             user: 'user',
             pass: 'pass',
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    port: 25,
    host: 'localhost',
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
  });

  var message = {
    from: 'noreply@yourotherdomain.com',
    to: 'whatever@thisdomain.com',
    subject: 'Confirm Email',
    text: 'Please confirm your email',
    html: '<p>Please confirm your email</p>'
  };

  transporter.sendMail(message, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
  });
```

I'm current triggering this through an restful api on express.js

this should work, i used this to set up my postfix on digitalocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04